# How to pass a string to an object class in Python

Tags: python, class, object

I have a long string that I'd want to build an object out of by parsing through it and pulling out certain values but I'm not sure how to pass the string to my class. I'd like to pass the string to the class, build an object from the info I pull from the string, and then return it.

```
 class Customer(stringWithInfo):

      def __init__(self, name, email, number):

         self.name = name 
         self.email = email
         self.number = number

     def getName(self, name):

        name = re.search("'name': '(.+?)',",stringWithInfo).group(1)
        return self.name

     def getEmail(self, email):

        email = re.search("'email': '(.+?)',",stringWithInfo).group(1)
        return self.email

     def getName(self, number):

        number = re.search("'number': '(.+?)',",stringWithInfo).group(1)
        return self.number
```

Comment: The place where you put 'stringWithInfo' is the superclass for the object. If you want to add 2 ways to initialize/create the object, you can use the *args parameter.

Comment: I would suggest you try parsing the string outside the creation of the object and pass the values in after. As it stands now,  the only way to create the object is by passing in a long string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
class Customer(object):

      def __init__(self, stringWithInfo):
         self.name = re.search("'name': (.+?)',",stringWithInfo).group(1)
         self.email = re.search("'email': (.+?)',",stringWithInfo).group(1)
         self.number = re.search("'number': '(.+?)',",stringWithInfo).group(1)

     def getName(self, name):
        return self.name

     def getEmail(self, email):
        return self.email

     def getNumber(self, number):
        return self.number
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class declaration:

```
 class Customer(stringWithInfo):
```

you're specifying `stringWithInfo` as your base class. This probably isn't what you want. Classes don't take arguments, they're not functions you call (I'm ignoring the metaclass for the moment, as it's not really relevant, but you can look it up if you're interested).

---

> I'd like to pass the string to the class, build an object from the info I pull from the string, and then return it.

The cleanest solution, usually, is just to write a separate factory function or class. This is because it separates whatever your class *does* from how you represent it in a string, and from whatever machinery (regex here) you use to parse the string.

Here it looks like you could write a much more generic parser to turn your string into a dict of {'name':'value'} pairs, and then your factory function becomes trivial.

However, if you strongly prefer keeping all this in the same class, you can just use static methods:

```
class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, email, number):
        self.name = name 
        self.email = email
        self.number = number

    @staticmethod
    def fromString(s):
        name = Customer.parseName(s)
        email = Customer.parseEmail(s)
        number = Customer.parseNumber(s)
        return Customer(name, email, number)

    @staticmethod
    def parseName(s):
        m = re.search("'name': '(.+?)',",s)
        return m.group(1)

    @staticmethod
    def parseEmail(s):
        m = re.search("'email': '(.+?)',",s)
        return m.group(1)

    @staticmethod
    def parseNumber(s):
        m = re.search("'number': '(.+?)',",s)
        return m.group(1)
```

(Note your factory methods *must* be static, if you insist on putting them in your class, because you don't yet have an instance to call them on).

You'd use it like:

```
c = Customer.fromString("'name': 'bob', 'number': '1', 'email': 'nope', ")
```

Comment: So if I were to go this route, how to I pass the long string to parse? `c = Customer.fromString(MylongString)`